# Позиционирование фонового изображения

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

возникла проблема с позиционированием фонового изображение. Вернее, спозиционированно оно все хорошо, но для адаптации все плохо. Проще говоря, на экране меньше 1440px, все элементы изменяют свои размеры соответственно с заданными параметрами, а вот фоновое изображение остается во всю ширину экрана. Если что, изображение выровненно по центру через тег `p` `text-align: center;`.
Так вот, по моему, все это дело решается через `@media`. Все бы ничего, но я не знаю как это сделать. К тому же, на фоновом изображение контентная часть находится справой стороны, слева там мало всего нужного и по сути вообще белый фон.
Вроде как понятно объяснил, ну в общем, плиз хелп ми, иначе тенотен уже не поможет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) кода. Без него трудно понять, что вы  имеете ввиду.

Comment: html: 

<div class="main-block__container-image">
                        <p class="main-block__image _ibg">
                            <img src="/img/mainblock.jpg" alt="COVER">
                        </p>
                </div>



css:
.main-block__container-image{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.main-block__image{
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: С кодом понятно. На будущее: чтобы добавить информацию к вопросу, его можно править. Теперь скажите, пожалуйста, чего конкретно вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Проблема с адаптацией. На экранах меньше 1440рх фон остается во всю ширину экрана, а остальные элементы при этом меняют свои размеры и положение согласно заданным мной параметрам. Как сделать так чтобы фон, как бы, обрезался с уменьшением размеров экрана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно, чтобы фон на малых экранах обрезался, а не растягивал страницу в ширину.

Для начала стоит всё-таки установить фон, а не изображение. В CSS для этого существует свойство `background-image`, а также сопутствующие:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="main-block">
    Content
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; /* Для наглядности */
  border: solid 3px yellowgreen;
  background-image: url(img/mainblock.jpg); /* Ссылка на фоновое изображение */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Цикличность фона */
  background-position: center; /* Положение фона в блоке */
  background-size: cover; /* Размер фона */
}

.main-block {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Этот код расположит фон с сохранением пропорций по центру блока, чтобы блок полностью им покрывался:

[image: Фон]

При этом он никогда не будет вылезать за пределы div.

Советую [почитать](http://htmlbook.ru/) про каждое свойство, чтобы расположить фон так, как вам нужно. В CSS для этого есть всё необходимое.

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень выручили